# What's the difference between async and async* in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making an application using flutter framework .
During this I came across with the keywords in Dart `async` and `async*`.
Can anybody tell me what's the difference between them?

Comment: yeah, super magical semantics from google geeks

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Marking a function as `async` or `async*` allows it to use the `async`/`await` for a `Future`.

The difference between both is that `async*` will always return a `Stream` and offer some syntactical sugar to emit a value through the `yield` keyword.

We can therefore do the following:

```
Stream<int> foo() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}
```

This function emits a value every second, which increments every time.

Comment: By marking a function as async* we are able to use the yield keyword and return a Stream of data.

Answer (score 301):

### Short answer

- `async` gives you a `Future`
- `async*` gives you a `Stream`.

### async

You add the `async` keyword to a function that does some work that might take a long time. It returns the result wrapped in a `Future`.

```
Future<int> doSomeLongTask() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 42;
}
```

You can get that result by awaiting the Future:

```
main() async {
  int result = await doSomeLongTask();
  print(result); // prints '42' after waiting 1 second
}
```

### async*

You add the `async*` keyword to make a function that returns a bunch of future values one at a time. The results are wrapped in a Stream.

```
Stream<int> countForOneMinute() async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}
```

The technical term for this is [asynchronous generator function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators). You use `yield` to return a value instead of `return` because you aren't leaving the function.

You can use `await for` to wait for each value emitted by the Stream.

```
main() async {
  await for (int i in countForOneMinute()) {
    print(i); // prints 1 to 60, one integer per second
  }
}
```

### Going on

Watch these videos to learn more, especially the one on Generators:

- [Isolates and Event Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=14)
- [Futures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=16&t=0s)
- [Streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=17&t=0s)
- [async / await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=18&t=0s)
- [Generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=19&t=0s)

Comment: 'Watch these videos' – would be great if you could provide *textual* references as well. Not everyone is fond of videos...

Comment: So perfect explanation. I'm impressed

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: what will happen if func with async* not yield but return a value?

Comment: @kent2508, Dart won't let you return a value from an `async*` function. You can only yield a value. However, you can call `return;` (without a value) to exit the function early.

Comment: So perfect explanation.

Comment: The explanation couldn't be better.

Answer (score 21):

## Solution, Origins and Insights

*This answer includes simplified and easy to understand examples*

### [`async`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/dart-async-library.html)

The async computation cannot provide a result immediately when it is started because the program may need to wait for an external response like:

- Reading a file
- Querying a database
- Fetching data from an API

Instead of blocking all computation until the result is available, the asynchronous computation immediately returns a Future object which will eventually "complete" with the result.

Example (This type of async call can be used only without returning a response):

```
void main() async {
  // The next line awaits 5 seconds
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  // Pseudo API call that takes some time
  await fetchStocks();
}
```

### [`Future`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Future-class.html)

> A Future represents a computation that doesn’t complete immediately. Whereas a normal function returns the result, an asynchronous function returns a Future, which will
> eventually contain the result. The Future will tell you when the result is ready.

- Future is appended when the async function returns a value
- Represents the result of a single computation (in contrast to a `Stream`)

Example:

```
Future<String> fetchUserOrder() =>
    // Imagine that this function is more complex and slow.
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 2),
        () => 'Large Latte',
  );

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var order = await fetchUserOrder(); 
  // App awaits 2 seconds
  print('Your $order is ready');
}
```

### [`Stream`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Stream-class.html)

A source of asynchronous data events.
A Stream provides a way to receive a sequence of events. Each event is either a data event, also called an element of the stream.

- Stream is a sequence of results
- From stream you get notified for results (stream elements)

### `async*` [(streams)](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams)

`async*` is an asynchronous generator that returns a Stream object. Made to create streams.

An example of using a stream and async*:

```
// Creating a new stream with async*
// Each iteration, this stream yields a number
Stream<int> createNumberStream(int number) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  // Calling the stream generation
  var stream = createNumberStream(5);
  // Listening to Stream yielding each number
  stream.listen((s) => print(s));
}
```

*Result:*

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

### *Bonus: Transforming an Existing Stream*

If you already have a stream, you can transform it to a new stream based on the original stream’s events.

Example (same code as before but with a twist):

```
Stream<int> createNumberStream(int number) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

// This part is taking a previous stream through itself and outputs updated values
// This code multiplies each number from the stream
Stream<int> createNumberDoubling(Stream<int> chunk) async* {
  await for (final number in chunk) {
    yield number*2;
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  // Here we are Transforming the first stream through createNumberDoubling stream generator
  var stream = createNumberDoubling(createNumberStream(5));
  stream.listen((s) => print(s));
}
```

*Result:*

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

### **Solution**

The `async` and `async*` are close relatives, they are even from the same library [`dart:async`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/dart-async-library.html)
The `async` represent a `Future` and a one-time exchange while the `async*` represents a `Stream`, a stream of multiple events

Answer (score 4):

Async functions execute synchronously until they reach the await keyword. Therefore, all synchronous code within an async function body executes immediately.

```
Future<int> foo() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 0;
}
```

Async* is used to create a function that returns a bunch of future values one at a time. Each result is wrapped in a Stream.

```
Stream<int> foo() async* {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

async* will always return a Stream

```
Stream<int> mainStream(int value) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}
```

async returns the result wrapped in the Future. So it might take longer time. See the below example:

```
void main() async {
  // The next line awaits 10 seconds
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
}
```